# Why does spiped use both nonces and ephemeral keys?

Tags: protocol-design, diffie-hellman, nonce, forward-secrecy

Colin Percival's `spiped` utility uses a pre-shared key and Diffie-Hellman with ephemeral keys to provide forward secrecy.  The protocol is summarized in [the project's README](https://github.com/polvi/spiped) under the section "Encrypted Protocol".

What is the purpose of the nonces (`nonce_C` and `nonce_S`)?  How are they useful when `x_C` and `x_S` are already chosen at random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the initial exchange of nonces, an attacker could replay a recorded handshake.  Although an attacker can't use this to replay actual packets, an attacker could possibly execute a denial of service attack if the process protected by spiped is not expecting a large number of connections.

The attack (assuming a modified spiped protocol that MACs the public keys directly with the long-term key):

1. Observe a handshake.  Record `y_C || h_C`, where `y_C` is the client's ephemeral public key and `h_C = HMAC(K, y_C)` (`K` is the pre-shared key).
2. Open a new connection and replay `y_C || h_C`.  The server sees a valid MAC, and presumably opens a connection to the protected process.
3. Repeat #2 until the protected process is overwhelmed.

Thanks to Ricky Demer for the discussion on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without the nonces, one could violate [explicit authentication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/what-is-implicit-authentication)

by replaying the `group_element || MAC_tag` messages.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the replay attack?  I don't see how the attacker could actually replay packets, since the other party will end up computing a different shared secret every time.

Comment: The attacker would just send the same `group_element || MAC_tag` to the party that message $\hspace{.26 in}$ was sent to before, even though that "party will end up computing a different shared secret every time." $\hspace{.15 in}$

Comment: Right. So the receiver accepts `group_element` as valid, and computes a new `y_SC` (a new shared secret).  The receiver then derives the new AES and HMAC keys.  How does the attacker now produce a packet with a valid HMAC tag?  The attacker can't simply replay packets because the HMAC key has changed, AFAICT.

Comment: The attacker doesn't "now produce a packet with a valid HMAC tag". $\;$

Comment: OK, so the extent of the attack is being able to successfully complete the handshake?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}\;$

Comment: Thanks.  OK if I summarize this in a separate answer?

Comment: That's fine. $\;$